# Iterating through python string array gives unexpected output

Tags: python

I was debugging some python code and as any begginer, I'm using print statements. I narrowed down the problem to:

```
paths = ("../somepath") #is this not how you declare an array/list?
for path in paths:
    print path
```

I was expecting the whole string to be printed out, but only `.` is. Since I planned on expanding it anyway to cover more paths, it appears that

```
paths = ("../somepath", "../someotherpath")
```

fixes the problem and correctly prints out both strings.

I'm assuming the initial version treats the string as an array of characters (or maybe that's just the C++ in me talking) and just prints out characters.?...??

I'd still like to know why this happens.

Comment: `()` is used for tuples, list is `[]`

Comment: a list would be `["../somepath"]`

Comment: Do any other languages declare single element arrays/tuples with brackets like that and also handle the use of brackets for their many other purposes?

Comment: @jamylak C++ and C use `{}`. I'm new to dynamic typing.

Comment: @jamylak: Note that sometimes you don't even need the parentheses to make a tuple, eg `a=3,4,5`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore What i was getting at is that you have to logically assume that `(value)` is probably not possible or how could you use brackets

Comment: @PM2Ring Thats great but i was specifically talking about having the parentheses, and even more specifically for one element.

Comment: @jamylak: Yeah, ok. Brackets (of one shape or another) do have multiple meanings in various languages. Eg parentheses are commonly used to group the args of a function definition or call as well as being used to group sub expressions in arithmetic. C and its close relatives use braces to mark block structure but are also used to group array initializers; also `<` and `>` are used as angle brackets as well as their use in comparisions.

Comment: @jamylak So it's not _that_ weird that Python uses parentheses to mark tuples as well as for grouping. But I don't think anyone would disagree that it can be slightly annoying that you need to include the trailing comma when creating a tuple of one element... even though it is a logical way to disambiguate that it is a tuple and not mere grouping. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
("../somepath")
```

is nothing but a string covered in parenthesis. So, it is the same as `"../somepath"`. Since Python's `for` loop can iterate through any iterable and a string happens to be an iterable, it prints one character at a time.

To create a tuple with one element, use comma at the end

```
("../somepath",)
```

If you want to create a list, you need to use square brackets, like this

```
["../somepath"]
```

Comment: the OP wants to create an array/list

Answer (score 0):

```
paths = ["../somepath","abc"]
```

This way you can create list.Now your code will work .

`paths = ("../somepath", "../someotherpath")` this worked as it formed a tuple.Which again is a type of non mutable list.

Answer (score 0):

Tested it and the output is one character per line

So all is printed one character per character

To get what you want you need

```
# your code goes here
paths = ['../somepath'] #is this not how you declare an array/list?
for path in paths:
    print path
```